# Does Kylo Ren claim Rey is a relative?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren, rey

In the movie, Rey's past and her possible relationship with other characters is left vague, though there are some hints that she

> is a Skywalker.

However, there is a rumor that in the Disney *Infinity* game, Kylo Ren calls Rey his "cousin".

Is that true?

Comment: He says "Curses", when injured.

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based

Comment: You're begging the question when you ask about Rey's parent**s**, since you're implicitly assuming that she has two, when we know that on at least one previous occasion a powerful Force user was born with only a mother, and no father.

Comment: @MikeScott - my answer addresses that

Comment: @CreationEdge - fixed the question so it is no longer offtopic

Comment: You guys crack me up. Completely rewrote the question...

Comment: @wogsland - what do you prefer - a question that CAN be asnwered and stays on the site, or a question which is against site rules and will be shortly closed and never answered?

Comment: Even if he said cousin, what makes you think it wasn't some unknown Solo relation?

Comment: I would be very surprised to learn that Rey is Luke's daughter, since the Jedi code forbids attachment, and it wouldn't be a good idea on the filmmakers' part to make him break the Jedi code, like Anakin.

Comment: @MikeScott Anakin only had a single parent if you believe Shmi's story. A single mother slave that went around telling people, even Jedi, that so-and-so powerful crime lord took advantage of her might find themselves in a pickle should the real father not want to be known.

Answer (score 11):

Specific to the source of this supposed rumor—the *Disney Infinity* game for *The Force Awakens*—this is a solid “No!” [according to this article on *Kotaku*](http://kotaku.com/no-disney-infinity-is-not-spoiling-star-wars-episode-v-1749629781):

> Only he doesn’t call her “cousin.” As Angry Joe later realized, hence
>   the removal of his video, is that what Kylo Ren is saying is “Face
>   me!”, which is quickly interrupted by “Curses!” when he suffers
>   damage.

This is the video that started this whole rumor storm:

And this is the video the author of the *Kotaku* piece made of his own gameplay to confirm that the character simply says, “Face me!” and then “Curses!” after he incurs damage:

Answer (score 8):

At present level of canon (December 2015), **nothing definitive is known about Rey's parents**. There are several canon **hints** (which may or may not pan out to be misleading vs true); and even more *fan theories*. None of them have any definitive canon confirmation, and likely won't till at least Episode VIII

> Where we find out that Luke and Leia are Rey's parents, tapping into Game of Thrones fandom, tying up unresolved storylines from Episides IV and V, and neatly uniting all the best fan theories. JUST KIDDING!
>
>  Other theories include:
>
>  * Luke (based on anvil-strength hints in TFA) and unknown woman (presumably, CORE world resident based on Rey having British accent and a theory that in almost all roles, that maps to Core - vs American accent for Outer Rim);
>  * Han and Leia
>  * Han and unknown woman
>  * The Force (the way Anakin had no father, except [NO MIDICHLORIANS](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112167/in-terms-of-midichlorians-does-spoiler-have-the-highest-count-in-the-sw-unive/112168#112168)!)
>  * Some other unrelated people

Specifically to address the rumor you alluded to, it was later updated and confirmed false by the same person who originally started it. [Kylo says "cursed", not "cousin" in the game](http://comicbook.com/2015/12/24/reys-identity-possibly-revealed-in-star-wars-the-force-awakens-d/).